# How to call one component function from another component

Tags: angular

Hi i am new for Angular and i am trying to call one component function from another  component and I was reading other similar questions but they have a scenario where the components are **child** or **sibling** components with the declaration on the html,but my scenario is diff for this i used below code but its not working(method not calling) can some one help me please

### MessageService :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    private _listners = new Subject<any>();

    listen(): Observable<any> {
       return this._listners.asObservable();
    }

    filter(filterBy: string) {
       this._listners.next(filterBy);
    }

}
```

### ClassA:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'header',
    templateUrl: `
        <section class="container">
            <button (click)="clickFilter()">Open filter</button>
        </section>
    `
 })
export class HeaderComponent {
     constructor(private _messageService: MessageService){}
     clickFilter():void {
         this._messageService.filter('Register click');
     }
 }
```

### ClassB:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'store',
    template: `<article class="card">
                 Test
              </article>`
})

export class StoreComponent {
    constructor(private _messageService: MessageService){
        this._messageService.listen().subscribe((m:any) => {
            console.log(m);
            this.onFilterClick(m);
        })
    }

    onFilterClick(event) {
        console.log('Fire onFilterClick: ', event);
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should change the subject into a `BehaviorSubject` and be sure that your service is a singleton

Comment: Are you able to create a Stackblitz that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi  i tried but not working

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

Your implementation is looking fine. The only issue with is where the `MessageService` is provided. You had declared `MessageService` in two different `Modules` of `HeaderComponent` and `StoreComponent`. Due to which its creating two separate instance of `MessageService` as a result they are not able to communicate.

### Fix

You should provide the `MessageService` in Module which is common to `HeaderComponent` and `StoreComponent`.

If you are not sure about the common Module then you can test it by providing in `AppModule`.

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [
    MessageService
]
```

Note : Do not forget to remove `MessageService` from the `providers` of other `Modules`.

Comment: How many places you have provided `MessageService`. Make sure its just in `AppModule` and no where else, not even in `Component` or `Module`.

Comment: its not there more i just provided in Appmodule

Comment: Rest of your implementation is looking fine as far as snippet share is concern. It would be quicker and easier if you can create the sample demo in stackblitz.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183487/discussion-between-abhiram-and-sunil-singh).

Comment: Just create the demo and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

MessageService must be added to parent module of ClassA and ClassB. Than your code works fine.